# Should I endorse someone on arXiv who emailed me randomly?

Tags: publications, arxiv

Someone emailed me randomly sharing a paper. The paper looks not crankish, familiar with the results in the field, but just someone who is not currently affiliated with any university. They have published in a reputable peer reviewed journal before, but have never posted anything to arXiv.

Should I endorse them? The paper looks professional (I have not verified that it is correct, but it looks like mathematics). Is there any risk?

They offered to chat with me about their work and it looks perhaps interesting.

Comment: https://info.arxiv.org/help/endorsement.html#what-are-my-responsibilities-as-an-endorser

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It seems clear that you are not obligated to act in any particular way here.  But since the author has published other work in a reputable journal and since the current submission looks like professional mathematics, I think that it would be reasonable to endorse them on the arxiv.  If you are interested enough to read the paper carefully enough to ensure correctness then that would allow you to make a definitive endorsement, but...isn't that placing the bar too high? No one said that your paper needs to be correct to be posted on the arxiv -- it just needs to be a sincere, serious effort by someone with something like the amount of training of a professional researcher.

I don't think you are in danger of losing your own arxiv privileges by a bad endorsement or anything like that.  The worst outcome I can think of is that somehow the word gets out that you are someone who is willing to endorse nonacademic mathematicians on the arxiv and because of this you get a flood of endorsement requests, but...if that happens you can just say **no** as many times as you want.  So there doesn't seem to be much of a risk here.

Comment: I ended up endorsing them. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: _If you are interested enough to read the paper carefully enough to ensure correctness then that would allow you to make a definitive endorsement_ - Not that you are implying this, but the arXiv endorsement page explicitly says this is not expected.

Comment: Great advice!!!

Comment: Great advice, because it implicitly means: don't trust any endorsements on ArXiv, they only mean that the endorsed entity "looks - on the first glance - like a scientific paper, perhaps like mathematics, written by somebody willing to chat about it".

Comment: @fdreger What do you even mean by "trust an endorsement on ArXiv"? Endorsements are not made public - you cannot see them on arXiv. And nothing implicit about it: endorsement is *explicitly* and intentionally not peer review of the paper - see https://info.arxiv.org/help/endorsement.html#what-are-my-responsibilities-as-an-endorser .  (But it's meant to be more than "looks on the first glance perhaps like mathematics" -  more like "would be plausible to be sent out for peer review by an appropriate journal".)

Comment: @fdreger Since anybody with an academic affiliation (including students) can get arxiv access without endorsement, "being on arxiv" is not considered a high standard. The endorsement process is only intended to be a bare minimum threshold to keep out _some_ spam and cranks; it's not peer review, and arxiv is not a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: @RichartRast : Did I say otherwise? I was hoping that a typical  ArXiv endorsement is based on something slightly deeper than "looks like mathematics" but I wasn't really betting on it. Upon the second reading of the question - I think it was just the specific wording that triggered me. The OP seems to have put quite some work to see if the text qualifies.